# Prevent lines from joining automatically with lines on another layer and over running them in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, style, linestring

I am having an issue where I draw a series of individual connected lines and then I want to continue on but with a different line type so I Duplicate the Layer and make the line style adjustments but then what I can't figure out is why the new lines on the new layer over run all the previously drawn lines on the original layer ?  I can delete the extras from the other layer but then when I save the changes it deletes the lines from both layers.

This seems like a bug to me but hoping there is a setting I don't know about since I am new to QGIS.  Currently using Version 3.22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the duplicated layer has the same data source as the original (there is a message displayed in the bar at the top of the map canvas that warns of this when you duplicate the layer).

[image]

[image]

Any edits made to the geometry or attributes are made to the single data source, and therefore, both layers. If you want to make such changes you will need to export the layer to a new data source (Right-click the layer name > Export).

[image]

You can, however, apply different styling to duplicated layers.

Comment: So Export > Save Features As ?  That seems to defeat the purpose of Duplicating the layer to save the majority of the preset properties then ?    I think I also broke the original layer  "Cannot reopen datasource C:/Users/User /Documents/GPS TIE IN.shp in update mode"

Comment: You can copy properties from one layer to another with Right-click > Styles > Copy Style > All Style Categories (or choose an individual category) then Right-click (the other layer) > Styles > Paste Style.

Comment: Ok thanks Matt that should help a lot.  Just getting used to this layering system.  Completely different concept to what I am used to.